# Setting value for an input field does not affect the virtual keyboard in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, input

If I set value for an input field which is in focus with the virtual keyboard opened it does not affect the keyboard suggestions.

The input field with some text: http://joxi.net/krDla3kSKZkxLr

```
document.getElementById('txt').value = '';
```

Text has disappeared correctly but it is still downthere in suggestions: http://joxi.ru/vAWKE5eHgVnlXA?d=1

If I enter new text it mixes with previous text in suggestions and the keyboard does not provide autocorrection and autocapitalization http://joxi.ru/brR5qMnC7np6GA?d=1

Comment: You could maybe unfocus (blur), and then set value, and re-focus.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do anything about that. The suggestions are probably only updated when a user types something in the virtual keyboard. I am no expert on how mobile safari works but my suggestion is don't focus on that because you will most likely get nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post is more a comment than an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: It's an input field for chat. When a user sends a message and the field is cleared autocorrection and autocapitalization do not work so it can not be ignored.

Comment: What I meant is not that it wasn't important but I meant that you probably do not have control over this through the web browser. Through something like native apis on an app you probably have much more control. I would suggest you find another online chat application that does this just to prove that it is even possible.